# Improper integral: Integrating over contour in upper half plane

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Okay so a friend and I are attempting the following integral

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x^3+1}\;dx$$

Our idea is to let

$C_1$ be the positive real axis from origin to $r$

$C_2$ be the integral along $|z|=r$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi/3]$

$C_3$ be the integral from $r$ to origin for $\theta=2\pi/3$

$\mathscr C$ be their concatenation

(Clearly we let $r\to\infty$)

Then we have $\int_{C_1}+\int_{C_2}+\int_{C_3}=2\pi i\underset{z=\exp(i\pi/3)}{\text{Res}} f(z)$

From Jordan's Lemma we know the second integral is zero

We are struggling to find

$$\int_{C_3}\frac{\cos z}{z^3+1}\;dz$$

We have tried letting $z=r\exp(2\pi/3)$ but are struggling with making this parametrisation useful. Any help with this last integral would be much appreciated.

Comment: For $r\to\infty$ it does unless I'm mistaken

Comment: $\int_{C_2(r)}f(z)dz = \int_0^{2\pi/3} f(r e^{i t}) i r e^{it}dt$ doesn't $\to 0$ ?
 $\cos z$ has exponential growth away from the real axis

Comment: But $\cos z=\Re[\exp(iz)]=\Re[e^{ix}e^{-y}]$ which is maximised for $y=0$ and estimation lemma results in $0$ given this.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. What is true is $\int_{|z| = r, \Im(z) > 0} g(z)dz = \int_0^{\pi} g(r e^{i t}) i r e^{it}dt \to 0$ with $g(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^3}$, because $e^{iz}$ is bounded on $\Im(z) \ge 0$. Write all the details, how did you come to $2\pi/3$

Comment: Because letting $z=r\exp(2\pi i/3)$, when parametrized the exponential part becomes $1$ and out integrand resembles that of $f$

Comment: It's because of the $z^3$ in the denominator

Comment: Exactly our contour $C_2$ is in the upper half plane

Comment: To be clear : $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x^3+1}dx =\Re(A)$ where $A = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{iz}}{z^3+1}dz = 2i \pi \text{Res}(\frac{e^{iz}}{z^3+1}, e^{i \pi /3}) - \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{i e^{2i \pi /3}z}}{(e^{2i \pi /3}z)^3+1}dz$ but it doesn't help since $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{i e^{2i \pi /3}z}}{z^3+1}dz$ isn't easier to evaluate. We can evaluate $pv. \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x^3+1}dx$ with the residue theorem, or with the Fourier inversion theorem, but  $\int_0^\infty$ seems out of reach.

Answer (score 2):

Such integral cannot be computed by residues only, it depends on the cosine integral. Let $\omega=\exp\frac{\pi i}{3}$. We have
$$ \frac{1}{x^3+1}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{\omega}{x-\omega}-\frac{\overline{\omega}}{x-\overline{\omega}}\right)$$
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^3+1}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\left[e^{-s}-\omega e^{\omega s}-\overline{\omega}e^{\overline{\omega}s}\right] $$
$$\mathcal{L}(\cos x) = \frac{s}{s^2+1} $$
and
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x+1}\,dx= \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{se^{-s}}{s^2+1}\,ds = \frac{\pi}{2}\sin(1)-\sin(1)\text{Si}(1)-\cos(1)\text{Ci}(1)$$
with $ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2-x}{x^2-x+1}\cos(x)\,dx $ having a similar expression.