# How to evaluate $ \displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac {\sin x}{1+x^3}dx. $?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration

I was wondering if we can use complex contour integration to evaluate the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac {\sin x}{1+x^3}dx.
$$
Since the integrand is not even, we cannot extend the integration domain to $\mathbb R$ and use the upper semicircular contour $Re^{it}$, $0\le t\le \pi$. We cannot use the keyhole contour either, since the integral of $\frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^3}$ over the lower semicircle $Re^{it}$, $\pi\le t\le 2\pi$ does not converge to $0$ as $R\to \infty$.

Using Wolframalpha to evaluate the above improper integral, it does not give a closed form answer. Therefore I was wondering if complex integration is not applicable in this case.

Comment: It is unlikely to have any nice closed form, since replacing the $3$ with a $2$ has the same problem. You can obviously express it as a sum of values of [trigonometric integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral) via partial fraction decomposition, but I would be extremely hesitant to believe you'll get anything more (the antiderivative will also be expressible in terms of trig integrals, but will only be elementary for special values; I don't see any reason to suppose $0$ is special, since there is no symmetry about it (e.g. being odd/even), it's just a root)

Comment: *Mathematica* gives $\frac{G_{1,7}^{5,1}\left(\frac{1}{46656}|\begin{array}{c} \frac{5}{6} \\ \frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{6},\frac{5}{6},0,\frac{2}{3} \\\end{array}\right)}{2 \sqrt{3 \pi }}$ were $G$ is the Meijer $G$ function.  But I'm not sure I would call that better "closed form" than the original integral.  (And the approximate numerical value is 0.610913.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559331/improper-integral-integrating-over-contour-in-upper-half-plane looks closely related. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057519/how-to-solve-int-0-infty-frac-cosaxx31dx

Answer (score 4):

*Without complex integration.*

Write
$$1+x^3=(x+1)(x-a)(x-b)$$ where
$$a=\frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad  b=\frac{1-i \sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\frac 1{1+x^3}=\frac{1}{(a+1) (a-b) (x-a)}+\frac{1}{(b+1) (b-a)
   (x-b)}+$$ $$\frac{1}{(a+1) (b+1) (x+1)}$$ to face three integrals looking like
$$I_k=\int \frac {\sin(x)}{x+k}\,dx$$ Let $x+k=t$, expand the sine to face the sine and cosine integrals. Back to $x$
$$I_k=\cos (k)\, \text{Si}(k+x)-\sin (k)\, \text{Ci}(k+x)$$

So, if $\Re(k)>0\lor k\notin \mathbb{R}$
$$J_k=\int_0^\infty \frac {\sin(x)}{x+k}\,dx=\text{Ci}(k) \sin (k)+\frac{1}{2} (\pi -2 \text{Si}(k))   \cos (k)$$

The formula is a bit too long to type here but you have the formula.